# How do I make CvVideoCamera not auto rotate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

My `CvVideoCamera` auto-rotates, and I would like it not to. [This has been raised on the bugtracker](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2673), but there has been no activity for a while.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Subclass `CvVideoCamera`, and just remove the rotation code. I wanted my orientation always to be portrait, so this was simple:

#### MyCvVideoCamera.h

```
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>

@interface MyCvVideoCamera : CvVideoCamera

- (void)updateOrientation;
- (void)layoutPreviewLayer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CALayer *customPreviewLayer;

@end
```

#### MyCvVideoCamera.m

```
#import "MyCvVideoCamera.h"

@implementation MyCvVideoCamera

- (void)updateOrientation;
{
    // nop
}
- (void)layoutPreviewLayer;
{
    if (self.parentView != nil) {
        CALayer* layer = self.customPreviewLayer;
        CGRect bounds = self.customPreviewLayer.bounds;
        layer.position = CGPointMake(self.parentView.frame.size.width/2., self.parentView.frame.size.height/2.);
        layer.bounds = bounds;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you ask and answer at the same minute ?

Comment: @Luke [Yes, I submitted them together.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) I spent ages researching this, and it seems to be a common enough problem, I thought others could potentially benefit.

Comment: Hi, how do you initialize myCvVideoCamera? I have it just like you, however, when my camera preview should be on, it is just blank, and I think the only problem is how I am initializing

Comment: @Isaac Exactly the same way you would its parent class.

Comment: When I tried your code above, I got the warning that the autosynthesized property (customPreviewLayer) would create its own member variable (_customPreviewLayer) rather than using the existing instance variable of the superclass. Since this clearly wouldn't work, I tried adding a \@synthesize customPreviewLayer = customPreviewLayer; line, but that creates an error. I ended up removing the property and changing self.customPreviewLayer to self->customPreviewLayer. Did you run into a similar problem, @tom-medley ?

Comment: I know it says to avoid this, but hats off to you. This is an incredible find. This was destroying me.

Comment: This worked really well for me.  I had to change `#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>` to `#import <opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h>` and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Does it possible that can import cap_ios.h to .h file?.

Comment: Sorry that I can only +1 your answer... that issue cost me hours to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

To make it work, I had to add:

```
@protocol CvVideoCameraDelegateMod <CvVideoCameraDelegate>
@end
```

to MyCvVideoCamera.h described above

and

```
@synthesize customPreviewLayer = _customPreviewLayer;
```

to MyCvVideoCamera.m

Answer (score 3):

Quick fix
Before initialize the CVVideoCamera add these lines

NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:self.previewImage];
self.videoCamera.delegate = self;